# Use sffamily in threeparttablex' table body

Tags: longtable, sans-serif, threeparttablex

I would like to use `\sffamily` for all elements of `threeparttablex`' `ThreePartTable`---the caption, the body and the notes---as I do below for a regular `threeparttable`. I've managed to change the caption and the notes, but I can't figure out how to change the table body.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[referable,para,flushleft]{threeparttablex}

% Use \sffamily in table
\newcommand{\tablefont}{\sffamily}
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}[1][\fps@table]{
  \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\@float{table}[#1]}
  \@tempa
  \tablefont%
}{
  \end@float
}
\makeatother

\setTableNoteFont{\sffamily}% Use \sffamily for ThreePartTable's table notes
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}% Use \sffamily in captions

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{table}
      \begin{tabular}{l l l}
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
        \midrule
        First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
        Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
        Third line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        \source Made up
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
      \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      \source Made up
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l l l}
      \caption{ThreePartTable}\\
      \toprule
      Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead
      \bottomrule
      \insertTableNotes\\
      \endlastfoot
      First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
      Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
      Third line & 123 & 456 \\
      Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
      Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
      Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Probably `\AtBeginEnvironment{ThreePartTable}{\tablefont}` is the easiest way.

Comment: @campa Good point. Should've thought of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use generic hooks. And because you've asked for changing the fonts only inside `threeparttable` and `ThreePartTable`, I've restricted the font change to those environments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[referable,para,flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}

% Use \sffamily in threeparttable and ThreePartTable
\newcommand{\tablefont}{\sffamily}
\AddToHook{env/threeparttable/begin}{%
  \tablefont
  \captionsetup{font=sf}% Use \sffamily in captions
}
\AddToHook{env/ThreePartTable/begin}{%
  \tablefont
  \captionsetup{font=sf}% Use \sffamily in captions
}

\setTableNoteFont{\sffamily}% Use \sffamily for ThreePartTable's table notes

\begin{document}
  Test text.

  \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{table}
      \begin{tabular}{l l l}
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
        \midrule
        First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
        Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
        Third line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        \source Made up
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
      \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      \source Made up
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l l l}
      \caption{ThreePartTable}\\
      \toprule
      Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead
      \bottomrule
      \insertTableNotes\\
      \endlastfoot
      First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
      Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
      Third line & 123 & 456 \\
      Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
      Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
      Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}

  Test text.
\end{document}
```

[image: threeparttable and ThreePartTable in \sffamily]

Alternative suggestion: Redefine the normal font family inside the two environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[referable,para,flushleft]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}

% Use \sffamily in threeparttable and ThreePartTable
\newcommand{\tablefont}{\renewcommand\familydefault\sfdefault\normalfont}
\AddToHook{env/threeparttable/begin}{%
  \tablefont
}
\AddToHook{env/ThreePartTable/begin}{%
  \tablefont
}

\begin{document}
  Test text.

  \begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{table}
      \begin{tabular}{l l l}
        \toprule
        Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
        \midrule
        First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
        Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
        Third line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
        Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        \source Made up
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
  \begin{ThreePartTable}
    \begin{TableNotes}
      \item[a] \label{tn:a} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      \item[b] \label{tn:b} Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      \source Made up
    \end{TableNotes}
    \begin{longtable}{l l l}
      \caption{ThreePartTable}\\
      \toprule
      Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
      \midrule
      \endfirsthead
      \bottomrule
      \insertTableNotes\\
      \endlastfoot
      First line\tnotex{tn:a} & 123 & 456 \\
      Second line\tnotex{tn:b} & 123 & 456 \\
      Third line & 123 & 456 \\
      Fourth line & 123 & 456 \\
      Fifth line & 123 & 456 \\
      Sixth line & 123 & 456 \\
    \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}

  Test text.
\end{document}
```

The result would be the same as shown before.